# How to change the displayed number of digits

Tags: php, mysql

Hi all just a very quick one.

How would I write in an sql query or php to change the number of digits displayed.

For example I am using this $values['ClientId'] which is a AI primary key, I know that until I get to 10 it will look like 1, 2, 3, 4,...,10, but I want it to look like 01, 02, 03.  or even 001.

Probably a real simple one but I c

ant find it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `str_pad` function:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

```
str_pad( $number, $padLength, $padWith, STR_PAD_LEFT );

str_pad( "1", 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT ); // gives 0001
```

Comment: Yes thats for rounding, but how to get 1 as 01

Comment: For adding additional numbers to the front, use str_pad()

Answer (score 1):

```
$input=1; //if you need 01 instated of 1 then try 
echo sprintf("%02d", $input);

  $input=1; //if you need 001 instated of 1 then try 
echo sprintf("%03d", $input);
```

please read this [sprintf](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php)